# Ext.util.JSONP.request always return "Uncaught ReferenceError: callback is not defined"

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, jsonp

I'm trying to login in sencha using another server.
The following code doesn't work and I don't know why. 
Always appears the same error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: callback is not defined" in console.

```
Ext.util.JSONP.request({ 
    url: 'http://myserver/api/v1/login-jsonp2/1',
    callback: function(data) {
        if (data) {
            console.log(data.results); 
            console.log('SUCCESS'); 
        } else {
            console.log('ERROR'); 
        }
    } 
});
```

Return:
    callback({"id":10,"username":"e002102","firstname":"Roberto","lastname":"Moussalli"})

I also try change the return to:
    {"id":10,"username":"e002102","firstname":"Roberto","lastname":"Moussalli"}
But I received another error: "unexpected token"

The content-type of response is text/javascript
And I also put in index.html the tag

```
< script src="http://myserver/api/v1/login-jsonp2/1?callback=callback"></script>
```

and

```
< script src="http://myserver/api/v1/login-jsonp2/1?callback=callback1"></script>
```

What is wrong?!?!

Answer (score 2):

[Ext.data.JSONP.request](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonP) will send an HTTP parameter with an auto-generated "callback" parameter which is unique to each request.

Therefore your server needs to change it on each request (see the PHP example in the API docs I linked).

```
    callback1({ "foo" : "bar" });
    callback2({ "foo" : "bar" });
    callback3({ "foo" : "bar" });
```